# Fix Bootstrap Tabs alignment while shrinking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to make a tabs section. It is looking good and I have used "nav-justified" class. However while shrinking the tab I noticed that the Global Indices Tab which is slightly bigger than other tabs is moving into the second line. It there any way to fix this?

**Before Shrinking:**
[image: Before]

**After Shrinking :-**
[image: After]

Comment: reduce the font size on smaller screen using media queries

Comment: Can you produce the code at JSFiddle?

Comment: `.nav-justified` makes all tabs have the same width, and there is not much to be done. As @LuckyChingi said, reduce the font size so that the text fits in one line. Another approach would be not to use the `.nav-justified` at all.

Answer (score 0):

I used media queries to control the width of the tab instead of font and it fixed it. Thanks all :)

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) 
{ 
.stock-tabs{ min-width: 170px; } 
}


<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
         <li class="active"><a href="#tabs-first" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FX</a></li>
         <li><a class="stock-tabs" href="#tabs-second" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">US Rate Futures</a></li>
         <li><a class="stock-tabs" href="#tabs-fourth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Global Equity Indices</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tabs-fifth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Commodities</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#tabs-sixth" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Volatility</a></li>
      </ul>
```